# Restassured response from one step definition, and other from another step definition is giving NPE

Tags: automation, cucumber, bdd, rest-assured, cucumber-java

So I have a feature A, and step definition A. and similarly feature B, and step definition B. In both this step definition there is "THEN validate that response is 200". And implementation of this, points to a common step definition (which is in step definition A).
The issue is when i am running class B, THEN validate that response is 200, fails.
Because its implementation is in class A, and response there is NULL. How should I handle this?

Comment: please, add code and error stack strace.

Comment: You have to make that REST call in feature B also..

Answer (score 1):

When you define a step which is common across features, then you are sharing the same step (and it’s associated stepdef). The variable that you are using in Step Definition A to store the response, is not shared in Step Definition B.

The best way to address this is to define a separate class for calling the REST API and use that as a common class for both features, as shown in the gif below:
https://nocodebdd.live/nocodebdd-demo-npe-issue

I have also attached a gif on how this could be done in NoCodeBDD. I am the creator of NoCodeBDD. I created this product to speed up automation of BDDs without having to write any code. I would love to get some feedback on the product from the community. You can download a free version from https://www.nocodedd.com/download

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to share your glue code across multiple features for which cucumber already provides a option under `@CucumberOptions`.

What I mean't by this is just provide the glue option details within your runner file which triggers the features. For eg:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "<Feature Files Path (eg: src/test/resources/features)>", glue = {"<stepdef package(eg: com.demo.stepdefs)>"})
```

This should make your glue code sharable amoung all the features present within `Feature File Path` details.